# Django registration and math captcha not playing nice with each other

Tags: django, math, captcha

I'm trying to integrate django-registration with [django-math-captcha](https://github.com/justquick/django-math-captcha), but I'm running into troubles. I followed the examples math captcha's github. If I subclass registration.forms.RegistrationForm with MathCaptchaModelForm or MathCaptchaForm I get different errors

My code and respective errors

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form, MathCaptchaModelForm) 
Error: Error when calling the metaclass bases metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
or
```

> ```
> class RegistrationForm(forms.Form, MathCaptchaForm)
>
> Error:Error when calling the metaclass bases.    Cannot create a
> ```
>
> consistent method resolution order
>   (MRO) for bases Form, MathCaptchaForm

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just extend MatchCaptchaModelForm as it already extends forms.ModelForm.

Comment: aahhh of course! because MathCaptchaForm already extends forms.Form! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also provide a Meta class that extends one of the models you're inheriting when you're doing multiple inheritance: class Meta(InheritedModel.Meta):